# Which one of them is correct?

Tags: punctuation, commas, sentence-choice

1. Dirty, but drinkable water can be used.
2. Dirty, but drinkable, water can be used.

I think 2 is correct because even if 'but drinkable' is omitted, a sentence makes sense. I want to know you guys' opinions! They both can be wrong or right because I make those sentences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of the two sentences given, I agree that 2 is better. In sentence 1, it's not clear that the word "dirty" applies to "water", rather than to the whole sentence. But I don't think I would use either of the sentences. I would say, without commas,

> Water that is dirty but drinkable can be used.

or , even clearer,

> Water that is dirty but still drinkable can be used.

That's ignoring whether you should  drink dirty water!